# Google Sheets + GoogleCredentials = "insufficient authentication scopes"

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am creating a server application that needs to read a bunch of spreadsheets. So we are using `GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()` from `oauth2client.client` because the server has access to a service account. For local development, I want to use my personal credentials, so I am using the Google Cloud SDK. I used `gcloud auth application-default login` to make sure that works.

Creating a service is then as simple as:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

And in fact, that has worked fine so far, for a bunch of the Google Cloud products.
However, when using the Sheets API I get the following error when executing any request:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: 
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/...
returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

This only occurs with the Google Sheets API, other APIs (such as the BigQuery V2 API) work just fine.

What I have already checked:

- The Sheets API has been enabled on the Google Cloud project
- I have access to the spreadsheet and editor rights to the Google Cloud project
- I tried various methods of creating scoped credentials, like:

  ```
  credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  scoped_creds = credentials.create_scoped(SCOPES)
  ```

  However, that does not seem to have any effect, since the `create_scoped` method simply returns self ([source](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py#L1113)).
- I created a service account on that project and set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to it. That also works fine, probably because it uses the `ServiceAccountCredentials` which actually has an implementation of the `create_scoped` method.
- I am using the latest version of google-api-python-client (1.6.2) and oauth2client (4.0.0)

Am I on the right track here or am I simply missing something really dumb?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the (slightly disappointing) answer to this question on the bottom of [the Google Identity Platform docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials):

> If using the Google Cloud SDK gcloud auth application-default login command to provide your own identity for use locally, the set of scopes is currently fixed, although it includes all Google Cloud API scopes. If you need a scope outside this set the recommendation is to use a downloaded service account key.

Comment: Quote seems to no longer exist in linked doc

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apiclient.discovery` instead of `googleapiclient.discovery`.  I had the same problem when I was passing too many args to `build()`, but once I removed those excess args, it worked, and the only difference in my code vs yours is which module i pull `discovery` from.